# Excel VBA Transfer cell data to specific parts or ranges in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I know a little about vba, and I would like to achieve this using vba.
I am transferring data from sheet to another sheet with some special case.

Given this situation:
In another sheet I have these ranges

- A4:B10
- D2:E10
- G2:H10

My data is something like this

```
AXX    |    Contact no.
AXX    |    Address
AXX    |    Name
AXX    |    Summary
BXX    |    Address
BXX    |    Name
BXX    |    Contact no.
BXX    |    Details
CXX    |    Address
CXX    |    Name
CXX    |    Summary
DXX    |    Address
DXX    |    Name
DXX    |    Contact no.
DXX    |    Address
DXX    |    Name
```

My identifier is in the first column (AXX, BXX...).

The expected output is:

```
Row no|    Column A    |     Column B     |    Column D    |    Column E    |
1     |                |                  |                |                |
2     |                |                  |    BXX         |   Address      |
3     |                |                  |    BXX         |   Name         |
4     |    AXX         |   Contact no.    |    BXX         |   Contact no.  |
5     |    AXX         |   Address        |    BXX         |   Details      |
6     |    AXX         |   Name           |                |                |
7     |    AXX         |   Summary        |    CXX         |   Address      |
8     |                |                  |    CXX         |   Name         |
9     |                |                  |    CXX         |   Summary      |
10    |                |                  |                |                |
```

As you could see, my identifiers are AXX, BXX... If they are similar I would count the no. of rows and compare it to the no. of rows in my set of ranges.
BXX was not placed next to AXX because the remaining row is 3 but BXX needs 4 so it will be passed on to the next range. Also there will be a blank cells separating other values as seen BXX and CXX.

For now, what I only know is to count the rows using For loop. Would like to seek your help for this thanks.
My Initial code to get row count

```
Dim aa, aaLastrow As Long

aaLastrow = ShtData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For aa = 2 To aaLastrow

        If ShtData.Cells(aa, 2).Value = ShtData.Cells(bb, 4).Value Then

            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aa, 1).Value = ShtData.Cells(aa, 2).Value

        End If

Next aa
```

I know my code is incorrect and I am not sure if this approach is on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Data As Worksheet, ToWs As Worksheet
    Dim vData, vDB, vArray
    Dim i As Integer, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim rngDB(1 To 4) As Range

    Set Data = Sheets(1)
    Set ToWs = Sheets(2)

    vData = Data.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vArray = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    With ToWs
        Set rngDB(1) = .Range("a4:b10")
        Set rngDB(2) = .Range("d2:e5")
        Set rngDB(3) = .Range("d7:e10")
        Set rngDB(4) = .Range("g2:h10")
    End With

    For i = 1 To 4
        n = 0
        rngDB(i).Clear
        vDB = rngDB(i)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vData)
            If vData(j, 1) Like vArray(i - 1) & "*" Then
                n = n + 1
                vDB(n, 1) = vData(j, 1)
                vDB(n, 2) = vData(j, 2)
            End If
        Next j
        rngDB(i) = vDB
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Im having a problem in this part n = n + 1
                vDB(n, 1) = vData(j, 1) it throws subscript range error

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A, "AXX")
```

will give you the count you seem to want. You can refine the range, and you can insert the reference to a cell instead of the hard "AXX". If you wish to use VBA you can call the function as `Application.Countif(Range, CountWhat)` where "Range" is a range you define in VBA and "CountWhat" is a variant.

Comment: but how can I move the data to another column if it will not fit to the remaining rows, just Like BXX?

Comment: I guess your question got down-voted because it doesn't indicate the rule by which data should be moved, nor does it show own effort. However your question about how to count rows was explicit and did include own effort. That is why I answered it.